# How to addEventListener to querySelectorAll and when triggered get element index(or id, value)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener, selectors-api

I'm making background selector in site menu, It will change backgroundImage when user clicks on spec. image (that triggers radio button). I want to do it using querySelectorAll(".selected"), loop it and set addEventListener(click, ..) get index(or id, value) and set backgroundImage using background_list array.

[image: Menu Image]

```js
var background_list = ["/images/air-balloon.jpg","/images/mary-christmas.jpg","/images/mountain.jpg","/images/panorama.jpg","/images/plants.jpg","/images/sunset-mountain.jpg","/images/underwater-star.jpg","/images/vinyl-player.jpg"...]
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-background-container">

    <div>
        <input                  
            type="radio"
            id="image-1"
            class="select"
            value="1"
        >
        <label for="image-1">
            <img src="/images/air-balloon-small.jpg" alt="Air Balloons">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input
            type="radio"
            id="image-2"
            class="select"
            value="2"
        >
        <label for="image-2">
            <img src="/images/mary-christmas-small.jpg" alt="Mary Christmas">
        </label>
    </div>
```

For example I have dozens of images

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".select").forEach( item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', arrow => {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url("${background_list[index]}")`
    })})
```

Is there any way to find triggered index(id or value)? And how would you implement code for this, what's easiest solution? I'm beginner in JS

Comment: `forEach` already provides this for you as its second argument: `document.querySelectorAll(".select").forEach((item, index) => { ... })`. See the always amazing docs on MDN for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the index of an element in an array while using these array iteration functions by adding extra parameters (index is the second parameter with forEach):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".select").forEach((item, index) => { // here
      item.addEventListener('click', arrow => {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url("${background_list[index]}")`
})})
```

Comment: I made critical mistake, I searched so long trying a lot of hard concepts but forgot to relax and check forEach documentation Xd